# Detection of lung sounds using a stethoscope and a sensor

Tags: sensor, detection

I am currently working on a on a project for detecting sounds which uses a stethoscope, where its one end is connected to a sound detection sensor which is further connected to an Arduino board. The Arduino board is connected to the laptop with the help of a USB cable which helps to load the program using the Arduino software.

The program is running and is getting uploaded into the Arduino board but when I try recording the sound using the sensor, all I am getting is a noise signal.

The sound that I need are lung sounds which is why I am using the stethoscope which is connected to the sensor. Even after replacing the sensors all I am receiving is just noise.

So kindly help me out with where am i going wrong?

The sensor is connected to one end of the stethoscope and the sensor is connected to the Arduino board.

[image]

[image]

[image: the code on uploaded into the arduino board using the arduino software]
[image: the data sheet of the sensor]

[image: expected outcome]

Comment: Where is the link to the datasheet for the sensor? Where is your code? "*... all I am getting is a noise signal*". What does this mean? What are you expecting? How is your laptop "listening" to the signal?

Comment: Is the input biased properly?  Is it hum? and is it shielded?

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to use an Arduino for this.  What you want is a *suitable* microphone on a PC or PC-class software platform, at least until you have your algorithms perfected.  Then perhaps you can consider a stand-alone embedded implementation.  But an Arduino has absolutely nothing to offer a PC as an audio collection device.

Comment: I agree with Chris.  Use Audacity to perfect your matched filter and detection scheme for whatever characteristics you are looking for. And plot Spectrum for noise.  Considering your source is unbalanced and probably floating with lots of stray noise, you may need a cap to earth ground.

Comment: Thank you Chris and Tony. But I will have to use the Arduino because as it is for my final year project and it should be included. But at the same time I will make the changes as you guys suggested and see what output I get.

Comment: I saw a "delay(600)" on your Arduino code. Compare that to the sample rate of the image of the audio waves that you posted. Also, that breakout has a comparator and will output a digital signal related to an audio threshold...

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the `delay` function? 600 milliseconds is a lot longer than you think. That's not a good sampling time.

Comment: If you "have to use Arduino" then you need to pick a different project for which an Arduino is appropriate - using grossly unsuitable parts is not a valid educational experience either.  Neither an Arduino nor this sound module is appropriate to *this* project.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple issues with your project:

1. It appears that your Audio detector (likely it is [this](https://robu.in/product/lm393-sound-detection-sensor-module-black/) module) you are using has only a digital output. So it provides an 1/0 indication that audio is present, but not an analog value that could be digitized.

Here is a cheap sensor that provides both digital and Analog signals:
[image]
You may be able to find local suppliers.

Notice that it has four pins, and provides both a digital and analog output.

2. Your second problem is that you are only taking an analog value every 600ms, that is not going to provide you with enough information on the incoming waveform.

You can find lots of bouncing ball type projects that would help you understand what you need to do:
[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/) is a relatively easy to follow project on Instructables that leads you through detecting audio waveforms ....or [another very thorough one](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sound-detector-hookup-guide) from SparkFun, but it uses a different audio board.
Both have Arduino sketches code to help you.